# PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GULFCLGLIVE.F_empserach (V_pr VARCHAR2)
    RETURN V_resultset
AS
    V_resultset   empserach_types := empserach_types ();

    CURSOR C_somebooks IS
          SELECT empmastid
            FROM empmast e,
                 (SELECT '%' || COLUMN_VALUE || '%'     n
                    FROM TABLE (
                             CAST (
                                 f_string_table (
                                     (SELECT UPPER (
                                                    CHR (39)
                                                 || REPLACE (
                                                        TRIM (
                                                            REPLACE (
                                                                REPLACE (V_pr,
                                                                         '  ',
                                                                         ' '),
                                                                '  ',
                                                                ' ')),
                                                        ' ',
                                                           CHR (39)
                                                        || ','
                                                        || CHR (39))
                                                 || CHR (39))    asd2
                                        FROM DUAL))
                                     AS stringtable))
                   WHERE COLUMN_VALUE <> '%%') l
           WHERE (UPPER (TRIM (empid || e.empname)) LIKE l.n OR V_pr = 'ALL')
        GROUP BY e.empname, empid, empmastid;
BEGIN
    FOR V_rec IN C_somebooks
    LOOP
        V_resultset.EXTEND;
        V_resultset (V_resultset.LAST) := empserach_type (V_rec.empmastid);
    END LOOP;

    RETURN V_resultset;
END F_empserach;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, what looks suspicious is line #2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GULFCLGLIVE.F_empserach (V_pr VARCHAR2)
    RETURN V_resultset            --> this
AS
    V_resultset   empserach_types := empserach_types ();
```

Function is supposed to return a **type**, not local variable (by its name). Therefore:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GULFCLGLIVE.F_empserach (V_pr VARCHAR2)
    RETURN empserach_types 
AS
    V_resultset   empserach_types := empserach_types ();
```

As of the rest of the function, can't tell nor test it. For more info (if it still doesn't work), provide test case.